# iOS Facebook SDK: migration to new version problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have an old application where I use the `FacebookSdk`. I want to migrate this `sdk` to the version `4.17`. The problem is that many classes has been deleted from this new version. I want to know what are the equivalent of `FBSession, FBSessionState, FBFriendPickerViewController, FBCacheDescriptor` and `FBGraphUser`.

I use the `FBGraphUser` to get the user information such as his `id, name...` . `FBSession`: in order to check if there is a `session` and I was also checking the state of the session by `FBSessionState`.

I searched about this problem and I found that for the user information i can use this:

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"email"}]
    startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
      if (!error) {
         NSLog(@”fetched user:%@”, result);
      }
  }];
```

But I'm really confused about the `parameters`. What are all the values that I can put?

Also for the `FBSession` I found that I can check if there is a session or not using:

```
[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]
```

But how can I check the states `FBSessionStateOpen, FBSessionStateClosed, FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed` ?

And what about `FBFriendPickerViewController, FBCacheDescriptor` ?

Answer (score 0):

### Here's the Paramters field info (this should stay roughly static with FBSDK, some of this is "core" which means it won't really change that much, but I'll update whenever I can):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

The format of the info below is the following, sort of, I just did this quickly:

**"parameter"**  **"type"**

**"description"**

> **id** numeric string
>
> The id of this person's user account. This ID is unique to each app
>   and cannot be used across different apps. Our upgrade guide provides
>   more information about app-specific IDs
>
> **about** string
>
> The About Me section of this person's profile
>
> **age_range** AgeRange
>
> The age segment for this person expressed as a minimum and maximum
>   age. For example, more than 18, less than 21.
>
> **bio** string
>
> The person's bio
>
> **birthday** string
>
> The person's birthday. This is a fixed format string, like MM/DD/YYYY.
>   However, people can control who can see the year they were born
>   separately from the month and day so this string can be only the year
>   (YYYY) or the month + day (MM/DD)
>
> **context** UserContext
>
> Social context for this person
>
> **currency** Currency
>
> The person's local currency information
>
> **devices** list
>
> The list of devices the person is using. This will return only iOS and
>   Android devices
>
> **education** list
>
> The person's education
>
> **email** string
>
> The person's primary email address listed on their profile. This field
>   will not be returned if no valid email address is available
>
> **favorite_athletes** list
>
> Athletes the person likes
>
> **favorite_teams** list
>
> Sports teams the person likes
>
> **first_name** string
>
> The person's first name
>
> **gender** string
>
> The gender selected by this person, male or female. This value will be
>   omitted if the gender is set to a custom value
>
> **hometown** Page
>
> The person's hometown
>
> **inspirational_people** list
>
> The person's inspirational people
>
> **install_type** enum
>
> Install type
>
> **installed** bool
>
> Is the app making the request installed?
>
> **interested_in** list
>
> Genders the person is interested in
>
> **is_shared_login** bool
>
> Is this a shared login (e.g. a gray user)
>
> **is_verified** bool
>
> People with large numbers of followers can have the authenticity of
>   their identity manually verified by Facebook. This field indicates
>   whether the person's profile is verified in this way. This is distinct
>   from the verified field
>
> **languages** list
>
> Facebook Pages representing the languages this person knows
>
> **last_name** string
>
> The person's last name
>
> **link** string
>
> A link to the person's Timeline
>
> **location** Page
>
> The person's current location as entered by them on their profile.
>   This field is not related to check-ins
>
> **locale** string
>
> The person's locale
>
> **meeting_for** list
>
> What the person is interested in meeting for
>
> **middle_name string
>
> The person's middle name
>
> **name** string
>
> The person's full name
>
> CoreDefault
>
> **name_format** string
>
> The person's name formatted to correctly handle Chinese, Japanese, or
>   Korean ordering
>
> **payment_pricepoints** PaymentPricepoints
>
> The person's payment pricepoints
>
> **test_group** unsigned int32
>
> Platform test group
>
> **political** string
>
> The person's political views
>
> **relationship_status** string
>
> The person's relationship status
>
> **religion** string
>
> The person's religion
>
> **security_settings** SecuritySettings
>
> Security settings
>
> **significant_other** User
>
> The person's significant other
>
> **sports** list
>
> Sports this person likes
>
> **quotes** string
>
> The person's favorite quotes
>
> **third_party_id** string
>
> A string containing an anonymous, but unique identifier for the
>   person. You can use this identifier with third parties
>
> **timezone** float (min: -24) (max: 24)
>
> The person's current timezone offset from UTC
>
> **token_for_business** string
>
> A token that is the same across a business's apps. Access to this
>   token requires that the person be logged into your app. This token
>   will change if the business owning the app changes
>
> **updated_time** datetime
>
> Updated time
>
> **shared_login_upgrade_required_by** datetime
>
> The time that the shared loginneeds to be upgraded to Business Manager
>   by
>
> **verified** bool
>
> Indicates whether the account has been verified. This is distinct from
>   the is_verified field. Someone is considered verified if they take any
>   of the following actions:
>
> ```
> Register for mobile
> Confirm their account via SMS
> Enter a valid credit card
> ```
>
> **video_upload_limits** VideoUploadLimits
>
> Video upload limits
>
> **viewer_can_send_gift** bool
>
> Can the viewer send a gift to this person?
>
> **website** string
>
> The person's website
>
> **work** list
>
> Details of a person`s work experience
>
> **public_key** string
>
> The person's PGP public key
>
> **cover** CoverPhoto

---

### Also, here's the current "Edge" stuff: The format for "Edge' stuff is this, roughly, I did this quickly:

**"Edge"**

**"Description"**

> **favorite_requests**
>
> Developers' favorite requests to the Graph API
>
> **request_history**
>
> Developers' Graph API request history
>
> **accounts**
>
> Facebook Pages this person administers/is an admin for
>
> **achievements**
>
> Achievements made in Facebook games
>
> **adaccounts**
>
> The advertising accounts to which this person has access
>
> **adaccountgroups**
>
> Ad account groups
>
> **adcontracts**
>
> The person's ad contracts
>
> **admined_groups**
>
> Groups the user admins
>
> **adnetworkanalytics**
>
> Insights data for the person's Audience Network apps
>
> **albums**
>
> The photo albums this person has created
>
> **apprequests**
>
> This person's pending requests from an app
>
> **apprequestformerrecipients**
>
> App requests
>
> **books**
>
> The books listed on this person's profile
>
> **domains**
>
> The domains the user admins
>
> **events**
>
> Events for this person. By default this does not include events the
>   person has declined or not replied to
>
> **family**
>
> This person's family relationships.
>
> **stream_filters**
>
> A list of filters that can be applied to the News Feed edge
>
> **friendlists**
>
> The person's custom friend lists
>
> **ids_for_business**
>
> Business entities can claim ownership of multiple apps using the
>   Business Manager. This edge returns the list of IDs that this user has
>   in any of those other apps
>
> **invitable_friends**
>
> A list of friends that can be invited to install a Facebook Canvas app
>
> **games**
>
> Games this person likes
>
> **groups**
>
> The Facebook Groups that the person belongs to
>
> **likes**
>
> All the Pages this person has liked
>
> **movies**
>
> Movies this person likes
>
> **music**
>
> Music this person likes
>
> **objects**
>
> Objects
>
> **permissions**
>
> The permissions that the person has granted this app
>
> **photos**
>
> Photos the person is tagged in or has uploaded
>
> **picture**
>
> The person's profile picture
>
> **tagged_places**
>
> List of tagged places for this person. It can include tags on videos,
>   posts, statuses or links
>
> **promotable_domains**
>
> All the domains user can promote
>
> **promotable_events**
>
> All the events which user can promote.
>
> **taggable_friends**
>
> Friends that can be tagged in content published via the Graph API
>
> **television**
>
> TV shows this person likes
>
> **videos**
>
> Videos the person is tagged in or uploaded
>
> **video_broadcasts**
>
> Video broadcasts from this person
>
> **applications**
>
> The Facebook apps that this person is a developer of.
>
> **checkins**
>
> The checkins this person has made.
>
> **feed**
>
> The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by
>   this person.
>
> **friendrequests**
>
> A person's pending friend requests.
>
> **friends**
>
> A person's friends.
>
> **home**
>
> A person's Facebook homepage feed.
>
> **inbox**
>
> A person's Facebook Messages inbox.
>
> **locations**
>
> A feed of posts and photos that include location information and in
>   which this person has been tagged. This is useful for constructing a
>   chronology of places that the person has visited.
>
> **mutualfriends**
>
> The list of mutual friends between two people.
>
> **notifications**
>
> The unread Facebook notifications that a person has.
>
> **outbox**
>
> A person's Facebook Messages outbox.
>
> **questions**
>
> The questions that a person has created.
>
> **scores**
>
> The scores this person has received from Facebook Games that they've
>   played.
>
> **subscribers**
>
> The profiles that are following this person.
>
> **subscribedto**
>
> The profile that this person is following.

Comment: Thank you but how can I check the session state?

Comment: If I pass `nil` to `parameters`, will I get all the user informations?

Comment: nope, Facebook is strict, they're the new 3rd Reich, not Trump

Comment: So I have to put all the parameters names that I want in the parameters fields. Is that what you want to say?